# Adding a basement to a photogrammetry

Tags: modeling, mesh, shrinkwrap, photogrammetry

To add a basement to a photogrammetry, I tried the answer givent in this question : [How to create a flat base to a photogrammetry model in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192625/how-to-create-a-flat-base-to-a-photogrammetry-model-in-blender)
But so far I am stuck after the step : *Add a shrinkwrap, set the target to your plane, vertex group to your new vertex group, set the mode to project on the Negative Z axis. Hide your plane.*

The sides don't appear. So maybe I am wrong somewhere ?
It seems to me that the only difference is that I am using verion 3.4.1.

I share a capture of the right panel, I can provide a video of the whole process if needed.

Any help welcome, I am new to Blender...
[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

I assigned to the group only the vertices of the perimeter. The only thing I did afterwards was adjust the size of the plane so that the projection is as perpendicular as possible to the terrain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe another newbie question : how do you select only the vertices of the perimeter ? If my object is cropped (with boolean modifier and a cube as operand) and has staight borders, it works with select boundary loops ; but in its original state (not cropped) using select boundary loops gives a strange result, vertices inside the model are selected too (it seems that I can't post an image in the comment ?).

Comment: You can edit the original post and add the image or the blend file (or only a part of it). That will help